# Design Issues in android development

Tags: android, eclipse

I am attaching one image to be designed.
I need to make one cricket ground with single image slice.
Slice need to be rotated in eight zone to complete ground.
I am rotating but by fixing position in left,top,right margin that is not working in all devices.

I want to generalize so that it works perfectly.

Comment: Way too vague, it's impossible to understand your intention. Also, there is no image attached. You mentioned you have code but it doesn't work in all devices - please attach code then.

Comment: Please show us some code and whatever you have tried.